# Multiply 2 HTML classes and output total using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiplication

I'd like to multiply the content of 2 below fields and output the total in another div (24 * £20.00):

```
<label class="tm-show-picker-value" for="tmcp_range_4">24</label>
<span class="price amount final">£20.00</span>
```

I have tried the below method using jQuery but i'm not greatly familiar with this - https://jsfiddle.net/e8shpr0e/

```js
$('.total').html(
  parseFloat($('.tm-show-picker-value').text()) * parseFloat($('.price amount final').text())
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tm-show-picker-value" for="tmcp_range_4">24</label>
<span class="price amount final">£20.00</span>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: Please include your code here too.

Comment: `parseFloat($('.price').text())` returns `NaN` because of the symbol in front of the number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code.

1. you should not use space in your classnames.
2. your "dollar" sign is resulting in error parsing your float.

use the [following code](https://jsfiddle.net/n343v2tq/).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tm-show-picker-value" for="tmcp_range_4">24</label>
<span class="price_amount_final">£20.00</span>
<div class="total"></div>



var quantity = parseFloat($('.tm-show-picker-value').text());
var cost = parseFloat($('.price_amount_final').text().replace("£", ""));
$('.total').text("£" + quantity * cost );
```

Comment: Or OP can use this selector: `.price.amount.final`

Comment: @SlipperyPete i second that. I didn't mention that because based on the terms used, i am guessing that the coder has meant to use 1 phase instead of separate classes

Comment: Nice! Beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Three problems:

1. In JSFiddle, you must include the jQuery library. Add this under JavaScript > Frameworks and Extensions > Version
2. Remove the non-numeric characters in the text. I would recommend doing this through `.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "")`
3. To chain class names, don't put a space in between them. Instead, put them next to each other, with a dot in front of each, like you would in CSS. It should be a valid CSS selector, like so: `.price.amount.final`

In summary, this is the fixed code:

```
$('.total').text( parseFloat($('.tm-show-picker-value').text()) * parseFloat($('.price.amount.final').text().replace(/[^0-9\.]/g, "")))
```

[Fixed JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e8shpr0e/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```js
$('.total').html(
 '£' + parseFloat($('.tm-show-picker-value').text()) * parseFloat($('.price').text().split('£')[1])
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tm-show-picker-value" for="tmcp_range_4">24</label>
<span class="price amount final">£20.00</span>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet.

```js
var priceRange = $('.tm-show-picker-value').html();
var priceAmount = $('.final').html();
var removeEuro = priceAmount.replace("£", "");
var total = parseFloat(removeEuro) * parseFloat(priceRange);
$('.total').text(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="tm-show-picker-value" for="tmcp_range_4">24</label>
<span class="price amount final">£20.00</span>
<div class="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your class in your html for 'price amount final' is three separate classes you need to add hyphens so the class is 'price-final-amount' I also cleaned up your code a little bit to make it more readable:

```
var mult = $('.tm-show-picker-value').text()
var amt = $('.price-amount-final').text()
var total = parseFloat(mult) * parseInt(amt)
$('.total').text(total)
```

and your HTMl looks like this:

```
<label class="tm-show-picker-value" for="tmcp_range_4">24</label>
<span class="price-amount-final">20.00</span>
<div class="total"></div>
```